# Iphone 5 crashes with IOS 8 DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER because it is greater than Int.max

Tags: ios8, grand-central-dispatch

dispatch_group_wait(dispatchGroupHealth,DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER) crashes on iPhone 5
floating point value can not be converted to Int because it is greater than Int.max

any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use  UInt64(UInt32.max) since iPhone 5 32 bit is not supporting DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER